# No-hair theorems for naked singularities?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, singularities, no-hair-theorem

For black holes, we have no-hair theorems that say, under certain assumptions about the matter fields, that they are uniquely characterized by just a few parameters. Are there any such theorem for naked singularities? For example, the Kerr–Newman metric has a naked singularity for certain values of the charge and spin, so we would have a two-parameter family of naked singularities. But it seems that this family isn't all-inclusive, since we can have things like Penrose-Hawking "thunderbolts"...?[Penrose 1999]

Penrose, "The Question of Cosmic Censorship," J. Astrophys. Astr. (1999) 20, 233–248;  http://www.ias.ac.in/jarch/jaa/20/233-248.pdf

related: [Entropy of a naked singularity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73171/entropy-of-a-naked-singularity)

Comment: Electrons can be viewed as naked singularities in the right GR formulation, so they'd have to be at least as hairy as an electron.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: I don't think that's right. There are fundamental reasons why subatomic particles can't be GR-style singularities. If electrons were naked singularities, we would have fundamental problems in physics, and we would observe electrons to have very different properties than they actually have.

Comment: See the end of this answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/6575/55483

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that the no hair theorems are proved assuming some form of cosmic censorship. So it seems that any such theorem about naked singularities would have to be proven in a very different way if such statements hold. It may be that there isn't any such description of naked singularities.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: Jerry Schirmer is correct. You're interpreting his statement incorrectly.

Comment: @BenCrowell I can definitely accept that possibility. Is there a quick explanation of my mistake?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: He's saying that *if* you take the Kerr–Newman metric and put in the mass and charge of an electron, you get a naked singularity. That doesn't mean that an electron *is* a naked singularity.

Comment: @MBN: I could be wrong, but I think the assumptions of the black-hole no-hair theorems are stationarity, electrovac, and a horizon (which implies asymptotic flatness). I don't think any of these indirectly implies cosmic censorship. I'm basing this on http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-1998-6/fulltext.html

Comment: @BenCrowell: You are probably right.